# Current location of the phone in android

Tags: android, react-native

Is their any paid or free application that can tell me the Longitude and latitude of the current location of the phone. I am using GeoDist in my current react native code, but not getting the exact current location of the phone on android. I would appreciate if If anyone can recommend me a paid or free code to get the current location of the phone. Below is my code that is not giving me the right calculation:

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

 var geodist = require('geodist')
    var sLat= this.state.latitude;
    var sLong =  this.state.longitude;

    var dist = geodist({lat: sLat, lon: sLong}, {lat: item.LatL, lon: item.Long2}, 'mi'
```

)

Thank you.

Comment: Google Maps? Just drop the red pin on your location on the map, and then expand the box at the bottom of the screen to reveal the coordinate.

Comment: @Anjali are you using react-native-maps library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code I want to suggest some changes to your code:

> Use **parseFloat()** for getting both **latitude and longitude** if you
>   want the precise location as float will always give you the precise
>   value.

Provide these permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then In your .js file do these changes:

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO
```

Take a state in **this.state** as

```
initialPosition: {
   latitude: 0,
   longitude: 0,
   latitudeDelta: 0,
   longitudeDelta: 0,
 },
```

Do this in **componentDidMount()**

```
 componentDidMount() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
  var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

  var initialRegion = {
    latitude: lat,
    longitude: long,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
  }

  this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion})

},
(error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
{enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000,});
}
```

then you can use this initialPosition state in your MapView.

Comment: Thanks. That was it.

Comment: @Anjali glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library named [react-native-fused-location](https://github.com/MustansirZia/react-native-fused-location). I've used the library one my previous projects. All you have to do is

1. Install the package

```
npm install react-native-fused-location --save
```

2. Link the package

```
react-native link react-native-fused-location
```

3. Declare manifest permissions

```xml
  ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    ...
        <permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <permission
                android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    ...
```

Then you can start using methods defined [here](https://github.com/MustansirZia/react-native-fused-location#api).

**Example**

```js
...
import FusedLocation from 'react-native-fused-location';
...

async componentDidMount() {
     const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, {
                        title: 'App needs to access your location',
                        message: 'App needs access to your location ' +
                        'so we can let our app be even more awesome.'
                        }
                    );
     if (granted) {

        FusedLocation.setLocationPriority(FusedLocation.Constants.HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Get location once.
        const location = await FusedLocation.getFusedLocation();
        this.setState({lat: location.latitude, long: location.longitude});

        // Set options.
        FusedLocation.setLocationPriority(FusedLocation.Constants.BALANCED);
        FusedLocation.setLocationInterval(20000);
        FusedLocation.setFastestLocationInterval(15000);
        FusedLocation.setSmallestDisplacement(10);


        // Keep getting updated location.
        FusedLocation.startLocationUpdates();

        // Place listeners.
        this.subscription = FusedLocation.on('fusedLocation', location => {
           /* location = {
             latitude: 14.2323,
             longitude: -2.2323,
             speed: 0,
             altitude: 0,
             heading: 10,
             provider: 'fused',
             accuracy: 30,
             bearing: 0,
             mocked: false,
             timestamp: '1513190221416'
           }
           */
           console.log(location);
        });

        /* Optional
        this.errSubscription = FusedLocation.on('fusedLocationError', error => {
            console.warn(error);
        });
        */
     }

...

componentWillUnmount() {

    FusedLocation.off(this.subscription);
    // FusedLocation.off(this.errSubscription);
    FusedLocation.stopLocationUpdates();

}  

...
```

Comment: Let me try this. I will let you know.